# Center a div in X and Y Axes within a CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering, css-grid

How would you center in X and Y a `div` element within a cell generated with CSS Grid?

I have a 9x9 Grid and each cell has a `<div class="tic-box">`.

If I inspect the element in Firefox with the grid guides enabled, I can see that the `divs` are top-left positioned. I tried `align-self`, `justify-self` and such as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout) instructions with no luck.

I know it's almost unnoticeable:

[image]

...but I want it to be perfect because it shows in certain viewports.

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site">
    <nav> TIC TAC TOE </nav>
    <div class="tic-board">
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
      <div class="tic-box">?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this CSS (btw I'm using just a bit of SASS):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url("../img/patterns/background.png") repeat;
}

.site{
  display: grid;

}
nav{
  grid-area: nav;  

}
.tic-board{
  grid-area: brd;

  display: grid;

}
.tic-box{
  text-align: center;

}




@media(max-width: 400px) {

  .site{
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 16.66666666666666667%);
  grid-template-rows:    5vh 50vh 20vh 20vh 5vh;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav"
      ". brd brd brd brd ."
    "pnl pnl pnl pnl pnl pnl"
    "ads ads ads ads ads ads"
    "ftr ftr ftr ftr ftr ftr";
}
nav{

}
.tic-board{

  $sz: 16.666666666666666666666667vw;
  grid-template-columns: $sz $sz $sz;
  grid-template-rows:    $sz $sz $sz;
  line-height: $sz;
  grid-gap: .5vw;
  margin: auto;
}
.tic-box{
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;

}


}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `.tic-box { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }`